# iOS Text Field augmentation: add small ? at right end: already possible? How?

Tags: ios, uitextfield

Planning a more concise UI, realizing it might be very helpful to be able to activate a tiny "?" at the right end of a text field, and when tapped, fires off an event to allow us to help our user, either via popup tip, new modal view etc.

I have been searching to no avail, and thought to ask here if this is attainable currently or will require a subclass of Text Field.

Direct question: how can we add a help icon "?" at the right end of a text field?

Comment: Read the docs for `UITextField rightView`.

Comment: thank you, sometimes the seemingly tough ones have simple answers ;) .. thanks, and next time, i will rtfm  ;)

Comment: hey @maddy, i am trying to mark your comment as an answer, not seeing how. I must be missing something simple... regardless, your note was all i needed, again, thank you.

Comment: It's not an answer, it's a comment. You can't accept comments.